# Logic apps replace "null" with "" or vica versa

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to compare the data in dataverse with a Excel file to see whether the dataverse rows needs to be updated or not.

I'm using compose on each item from dataverse and a combination of compose, json parse and select to create two output values that I can compare to see if they match or not. I have to do this because as far as I can tell Logic Apps has no sane way of comparing data otherwise.

The outputs are working as intended the only problem is that fields with no value from dataverse show up as "name": "null" and the Excel data with no value shows up as "name": "" which causes my compare to fail.

Is there any to easily replace all "null" or "" with either "" or "null"?

Dataverse "output" example

```
[
  {
    "name": "john"
    "last": "doe"
    "address": "null"
  }
]
```

Excel "output" example

```
[
  {
    "name": "john"
    "last": "doe"
    "address": ""
  }
]
```

The actual data has many more fields so I would prefer to somehow just look over the whole "output" and match anything that is either "" or "null" and replace it with something and not go over every possible field one by one.

Comment: Is the value an actual `null` value, or is it a string saying "null"?

Answer (score 2):

I found a "solution".

```
if(empty(items('myAction')?['myActionField']), '', items('myAction')?['myActionField'])
```

This checks if the field is empty or not. If its empty, the value '' is assigned thus creating a (empty) string type field. If its not empty, the original value is applied.

The downside is that this cannot possible be very efficient and you have to do this for every field so if you have a lot of fields it takes a lot of time. In my case I "only" have 30 or so so its still somewhat manageable.

A better way would be if you could just loop over a "value" array and remove/convert all null values in one go. Or create a mapping that tells logic apps what field type a field so be. But I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a [Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) action anyway, instead of getting a dynamic content for your address field directly, you can just use the [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#if) and [`equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#equals) functions in an expression, something like `if(equals(__your_source_field__, 'null'), '', __your_source_field__)`.

[image]

Then the output of the `Compose` action won't have "null" values, and you can proceed with comparison as requried.

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps support a lot of expressions. One set of expressions they support are String functions. And one of those functions is `Replace(text, oldText, newText)`.

If the value you're trying to replace is an actual string holding "null" as its value, try this expression to replace `null` with an empty string:

`replace(output, 'null', '')`

##### Logic Apps string functions

[image: Logic App string functions]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this isn't working. Looks like this function cannot be used if the field type is Null. Is there any way to "map" a field type? E.g. tell logic apps to treat null field types as a string field?

I'm new to logic apps but its data formatting capabilities seem very poor to me compared to what I'm used to.